# How to find which account (email) has user used to log into my google-fit based android app?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, user-identification

I am trying to make an android app based on google-fit.

What I am trying to achieve is that I create an account for the user on my website as soon as the user chooses an account using the app.

Here is the code base that I want to build up upon (It is just the basic registration sample code) https://github.com/ishanatmuz/GoogleFitTest/tree/829051b7739ee9d8871c3ba9e5f21dfb17f4f3d7

[onConnected](https://github.com/ishanatmuz/GoogleFitTest/blob/829051b7739ee9d8871c3ba9e5f21dfb17f4f3d7/app/src/main/java/com/ishan1608/googlefittest/MainActivity.java#L117) is called when the user has succesfully signed in and provided the permissions. I am [calling my own function](https://github.com/ishanatmuz/GoogleFitTest/blob/829051b7739ee9d8871c3ba9e5f21dfb17f4f3d7/app/src/main/java/com/ishan1608/googlefittest/MainActivity.java#L126) to do further work which is basically this :

1. Get the information (at least email) of the user who just signed in.
2. Send the user to my server for registration.
3. Continue with the rest of the app.

I need help figuring out how to do the step 1.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `onConnected()` method, you can get it with:

```
Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Comment: I was able to get AccountName successfully but not DisplayName. I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person.getDisplayName()' on a null object reference

Comment: Here are the changes that I made https://github.com/ishanatmuz/GoogleFitTest/commit/967df7bd214fe2f0d8125fd44c2fb877adb5a582

Comment: `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson()` is probably returning null because you don't have the permission to see the details for the user. When building the `GoogleApiClient`, make sure to add the right scope. See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html

Comment: I am sorry I meant to accept your answer as correct before you asking.
I think the error is because I haven't added appropriate Scopes. so I tried this.

.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)

But this is still giving me the null pointer reference error.

Comment: Try `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)` instead.

Comment: I am referring from here https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.html#getCurrentPerson(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient) 

I have added both the Scopes Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN and Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE

It is still giving me the same null pointer reference error.


Here are the changes https://github.com/ishanatmuz/GoogleFitTest/commit/8ce5aedd5fa8614653d98016f99e745b90f51f95

Comment: hmm.. Sorry, I'm out of ideas. :(
Try posting a new question about getting the user profile and put the code on how you are initializing your Google Api Client in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75064/discussion-between-ishan-and-anyonymous2324).

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @Anyonymous2324 I figured out the solution. There is little more to do than what's mentioned in the answer below. So I thought it would be best for anyone who stumbles upon here in future; if I put it all together.

To get the accountName (email) or Display Name (user's name), the code required is the same as mentioned by @Anyonymous2324

```
Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
String accountName = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

But to get this to work there are a few things that are needed to be done.

1. Go to [Developer's console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and add ***Google+ API*** for your project (This is required for the use of any Google+ related work, in our case it is gathering of user name).
2. We need to add permission to access the accounts of the device, by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` to the manifest.
3. In your `GoogleApiClient.Builder` add the Plus API like this `.addApi(Plus.API)`
4. We also need to add some scopes so that `getDisplayName` can work. These are `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)` and `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)`

It is mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/People.html#getCurrentPerson(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) that the `getCurrentPerson` method can return `null` if the required scopes are not specified or there is a network failure. Therefore it is better to check the `currentPerson` object before calling `getDisplayName` on it.
The complete code then looks like :

```
Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mClient);
if(currentPerson != null) {
    String currentPersonName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    Log.d(TAG, currentPersonName);
    logStatus(currentPersonName);
}
```

Since the documentation mentions that the returned value can be null in case of network error; adding permission for INTERNET seems like a good idea. But on my phone it was working without the internet connection. I guess it was taking the information from Google+ app on my phone and not going to the internet altogether, so I didn't had to use internet.

But don't take my word on it and test yourself.

Comment: Thanks, works like charm.

I'd missed on providing the `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)` and `.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)`